# LevelDB Building and Performance

Tags: leveldb

I've managed to build levelDB by doing a git clone of levelDB, do a make which produces this:

```
[root@ip-xxx leveldb-master]# ls -ltr
total 88
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Apr 15 13:58 util
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   535 Apr 15 13:58 TODO
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Apr 15 13:58 table
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  8212 Apr 15 13:58 README.md
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Apr 15 13:58 port
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   509 Apr 15 13:58 NEWS
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 15424 Apr 15 13:58 Makefile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1484 Apr 15 13:58 LICENSE
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    52 Apr 15 13:58 issues
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    20 Apr 15 13:58 include
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    19 Apr 15 13:58 helpers
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  4096 Apr 15 13:58 doc
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  4096 Apr 15 13:58 db
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  1648 Apr 15 13:58 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root  7459 Apr 15 13:58 build_detect_platform
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   293 Apr 15 13:58 AUTHORS
-rw-r-----. 1 root root  1127 Jun 21 13:34 build_config.mk
drwxr-x---. 7 root root  4096 Jun 21 13:35 out-shared
drwxr-x---. 7 root root  4096 Jun 21 13:35 out-static
```

So now I see a bunch of guides online that say to do this:

```
cp --preserve=links libleveldb.* /usr/local/lib
cp -r include/leveldb /usr/local/include/
```

I can't seem to find anything with libleveldb.* after doing the make command.

Also how would I invoke the db_bench to get those rough performance metrics it can produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use files under directory `out-static`:

```
out-static/libleveldb.a
out-static/db_bench
```

It's ok if you want to use these ones under `out-share`.
You can run a command `find * -name db_bench` to find them.

Comment: Thanks didnt bother to look into those two directories for anything.